# how can I grab all the points plotted on the curve if I click on the curve in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

I have worked with the mouse events where, if I click on the particular point on the scatter plot, I get the coordinates of that particular point. Is the same possible to grab the points on that particular curve if I click on that curve using matplotlib events?

This is the code I use to get the mouse coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
    print(event.xdata, event.ydata)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to pick one point?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222774/python-matplotlib-get-data-with-cursor-from-plot

Comment: This yields skewed coords?